# How to make child component to process only those events it can process, leaving other ones intact?

Tags: java, swing, events

If child component has mouse listener added, then mouse events are processed in it, and mouse listener from parent component does not hear them.

This situation demonstrated in code below.

What is I want to separate processing with finer grain? For example, process double clicks in one component and single clicks in another. How to accomplish that?

**UPDATE**

In example below, if check box is ON, then child (yellow square) is processing mouse events. In this situation, parent (grey) stops processing single clicks. I want parent to still process single clicks simultaneously with child process double clicks.

```
package tests;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Try_ChildEvents {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if( e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 2 ) {
                    System.out.println("Double clicked inside inner");
                }
            }
        };



        final JPanel inner = new JPanel();
        {
            inner.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
        inner.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);

        JPanel outer = new JPanel();
        {
            outer.setLayout(null);
            outer.add(inner);
            inner.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
        }
        outer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if( e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 1 ) {
                    System.out.println("Single clicked in outer");
                }
            }
        });

        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Enable events", true);
        check.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ) {
                    inner.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                }
                else {
                    inner.removeMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(check, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(outer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I did as @camickr sadi and it worked but I don't understand, why? Why doesn't dispatched event go back to the children again?

```
package tests;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Try_ChildEvents {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class JPanelWithTurnableListener extends JPanel {

            final MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if( e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 2 ) {
                        System.out.println("Double clicked inside inner");
                    }
                    else {
                        MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(
                                (Component) e.getSource(), 
                                e.getID(), 
                                e.getWhen(), 
                                e.getModifiers(), 
                                e.getX(), 
                                e.getY(), 
                                e.getXOnScreen(), 
                                e.getYOnScreen(), 
                                e.getClickCount(), 
                                e.isPopupTrigger(), 
                                e.getButton()
                                );
                        getParent().dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
                    }
                }
            };

            boolean on;

            public JPanelWithTurnableListener() {
                setBackground(Color.yellow);
                addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
            }

            boolean isOn() {
                return on;
            }

            void setOn(boolean newValue) {
                boolean oldValue = this.on;
                if( newValue != oldValue ) {
                    this.on = newValue;
                    if( newValue ) {
                        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                    }
                    else {
                        removeMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                    }
                }

            }

        }





        final JPanelWithTurnableListener inner = new JPanelWithTurnableListener();

        JPanel outer = new JPanel();
        {
            outer.setLayout(null);
            outer.add(inner);
            inner.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
        }
        outer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if( e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 1 ) {
                    System.out.println("Single clicked in outer");
                }
            }
        });

        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Enable events", true);
        check.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ) {
                    inner.setOn(true);
                }
                else {
                    inner.setOn(false);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(check, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(outer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have a child component ignore the mouse listener from it's parent component and only listen to it's own?

Comment: _"For example, process double clicks in one component and single clicks in another."_ - this program seems to fulfill the requirements when I tested it. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Opposite. I want parent listener to hear clicks inside child

Comment: @peeskillet see my update please; in example child intercepts events; I want to disable this

Comment: Do you mean that you want to process events in the component **and** propagate the event to component's parent after that? Or do you want the parent to disable the child's component listener?

Comment: @GermannArlington closer to first suggestion. I want process event in child, but if this event was not usefull for child then propagate it to parent

Comment: Then I think that you are looking for this - http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077218/core-java/java-and-event-handling.html

Comment: @GermannArlington I don't see the answer there

Comment: Look for `public boolean handleEvent(Event e)`

Comment: @GermannArlington it is not clear from the article, how to control return value of `handleEvent()`. in listeners I see no way to reach this value.

Comment: `I want parent to still process single clicks simultaneously with child process double clicks.` - so where is your code to re-dispatch the event?

Comment: Your child will need to implement `public boolean handleEvent(Event e)` and `return false;` in order for the event to propagate to the parent.

Comment: @GermannArlington I need do this instead of adding listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Component.dispatchEvent(...)` method to redispatch the event to the parent component. You will need to create a new MouseEvent.

See the GlassPane example from [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). It re-dispatches events from the glass pane to the component under the glass pane.

Comment: Will component receive that event, which was redispatched by it? Need I filter it?

Comment: `Need I filter it?` - isn't that the point of your question. All events will go to the child automatically. So the child listener needs to handle the events, either by processing, re-dispatching or ignoring.

Comment: I mean, if child will redispatch an event, won't it receive it again, causing endless loop?

Comment: I did how you said and it worked. But I don't understand, why doesn't dispatched event goes to the child again? How is it differs from original event? Or this depends on `dispatchEvent()` contract?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, When a MouseEvent is generated the Java code searches for the component that was clicked and specifically passes the event to that component, probably by using the dispatchEvent() method. You are bybassing the standard Java search code and dispatching the event directly to a component. There is no recursion involved.

Comment: @camickr and how can I simulate the process you described? I.e. post an event in a manner, causing search for child to dispatch?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, I don't know the internals of the Java classes. Why do you think you need to do something like this? I guess you can always use a `Robot` to create a MouseEvent, but I suspect you are complicating your code. The whole point of your question is to avoid the default processing of Java classes.